# Set datasource of particular cell's combobox based on another column of particular row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, infragistics

```
private void dgGrid_CellListSelect(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "ColumnA")
    {
        UltraGridRow selectedItem = ((UltraCombo)e.Cell.EditorControlResolved).SelectedRow;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            //Option A
            cmbColumnB.DataSource = GetUISender<someBF>().RetrieveData(dataset).dataTable;
            cmbColumnB.DataBind();

            //Option B
            //((UltraCombo)e.Cell.Row.Cells["ChipSetID"].EditorControlResolved).DataSource = GetUISender<someBF>().RetrieveData(dataset).dataTable;
        }

    }
}
```

There is a button that allow the datagrid to add new row. 
This datagrid have 2 columns and both columns are `UltraCombo`. `ColumnB` combobox's dataSource will based on `ColumnA`. Based on the above code, it works if the datagrid only have 1 row, but once user add another row, both row's `ColumnB` will be sharing the same DataSource.

How to make sure `ColumnB`'s DataSource stay independently without affecting other rows? It's very obvious that this happened because every row are sharing the same component which is `cmbColumnB` but I'm not sure on how to remove the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution which is everytime create a new `UltraCombo` and bind it to the particular cell's `EditorControl`

```
private void dgGrid_CellListSelect(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "ColumnA")
    {
        UltraGridRow selectedItem = ((UltraCombo)e.Cell.EditorControlResolved).SelectedRow;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            UltraCombo cmbValue = new UltraCombo();
            cmbValue.LimitToList = true;
            cmbValue.DropDownStyle = UltraComboStyle.DropDownList;
            cmbValue.DataSource = GetUISender<someBF>().RetrieveData(dataset).dataTable;
            cmbValue.ValueMember = someDS.someDT.someColumnIDColumn.ColumnName;
            cmbValue.DisplayMember = someDS.someDT.someColumnDescriptionColumn.ColumnName;
            cmbValue.BindingContext = someDg.BindingContext;
            cmbValue.DataBind();
            e.Cell.Row.Cells["ColumnB"].EditorControl = cmbValue;
            e.Cell.Row.Cells["ColumnB"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList;

        }

    }
}
```